# 1980's horror/Sci-Fi animated movie involving people and kids getting stabbed and beheaded

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, horror

Looking for the title of an 1980's horror/Sci-Fi animated movie. I was 5-7 years old, so it had to be 1982-84-ish.

Ultra violent, people and kids getting stabbed and beheaded, blood and guts might have been on a different planet.

I think it may have the word(s) 'planet' or 'horror' in it.

I saw it in the movie theater with my dad. Had nightmares for weeks, mom was pissed.

I saw it in the United States in downtown Virginia Beach, Virginia. I’m going to say it was in English because I was too young to read subtitles quickly enough for a movie.

Any help I would definitely appreciated, I can die a happy man when I get the name of that dang title.

Comment: Have you managed to rule any similar movies out?

Comment: Just top movies animated movies horror/sci fi from the 80s that I googled.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to name any similar movies that you know aren't the one you're looking for. That way, anyone looking to answer this question can rule those out right away and keep searching till they find something different.

Comment: No, I watched it (Heavy Metal). I just remember the movie being really gory and violent.

Comment: Where did you see this film (i.e. what country)? Was it in English?

Comment: United States in downtown Virgina Beach, Im going to say ti was in English because I was too young to read subtitles quickly enough for a movie.

Comment: @King Jeruz I've been goggling lists of english language fantasy/sf/horror films of the 80s. There are not many but I stumbled across something called Fire and Ice from 1983. It doesn't seem to resemble much of what you describe and I have not seen it myself but take a look at the wikipedia page and see if it rings any bells. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_Ice_(1983_film)

Comment: Another possibility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starchaser:_The_Legend_of_Orin (not particularly gore, but still more adult-oriented)